# Select last 4 row from every category in my post table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a post table for my blog application.

**Table structure:**

```
post_id  post_title  post_description category_id created_time status
```

i want to select last 4 post of each category from my table. How do i do that. I m using mysql database.

Comment: Post your related tables' `create table code`, what have you tried so far, sample input and expected output. Thank you.

Comment: A standard top n per group problem

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following query:

I've assumed your table name is **`BLOG`**

```
SELECT
    t.post_title,
    t.post_description,
    t.category_id,
    t.created_time
FROM
    (
        SELECT
          *,
          IF (@prev = category_id ,@cn := @cn + 1 ,@cn := 0) SL,
          @prev := category_id
        FROM blog,(SELECT @cn := 0, @prev := 0) var
        ORDER BY category_id, created_time DESC
    ) t
WHERE   t.SL < 4;
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/80a3e/1/0)

**Note:** If you want to grab latest 5 records from each category then just need to change the following line as follows:

`WHERE  t.SL < 5;`

**Explanation:**

1. First sort out the rows according to `category id` so that the rows
   belonging to the same category stay together.
2. Then sort this according to `created_time` `DESC`.
3. Now you got a result set where the rows are sorted according to
   `category_id` and `created_time DESC`.
4. Now assign a flag value which will indicate the corresponding
   position of the post in each category. (this flag value in this case
   `SL` starts from `0`). If you see a row under the same category then
   just assign the next value of `SL` to it. And if you see a row under
   a different category `(i.e. new category)` then reset the value of
   `SL` to `0`.
5. Doing the above you will finally get a result where the rows are
   sorted according to category_id and created_time DESC along with a
   flag value(`SL`) having the corresponding position in the result set.
6. Now if you filter those records where the flag value (SL) contains
   value less than `4` from this result set you will get those records
   which are among the top `4` records in each category.

Steps `1 to 5` are covered by the following query (it's the inner query in the given query):

```
SELECT
   *,
   IF (@prev = category_id ,@cn := @cn + 1 ,@cn := 0) SL,
   @prev := category_id
 FROM blog,(SELECT @cn := 0, @prev := 0) var
 ORDER BY category_id, created_time DESC;
```

[**Demo of this query only**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/80a3e/2/0)

Please check the `SL` value of each row. I hope you will get it.

Comment: Thank you . It works! but i can't understand some of its syntax. I never used this kind of query statement. I want to understand this kind of query. Where to i learn. Can u give me a link ?

Comment: please go through the explanation part twice or thrice times. Then ask me if you don't understand anything.

Comment: Have you got it?@RieadHossion

Answer (score 0):

You can use NOT EXISTS()

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable t
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM YourTable s
                 WHERE t.post_id = s.post_id 
                   AND t.created_time < s.created_time
                 GROUP BY post_id
                 HAVING count(*) > 3)
```

I didn't know what is the uniqueness of each row, I assumed post_id. If its also post_title/category_id ETC, then add it to the group by clause and a relation condition